# Error on loading widget in 7.0

Tags: android, widget

I have an app with a custom widget (used GridLayout, LinearLayout, ProgressBar). It works in Android 4.3-6.0. However, when deployed to 7.0+, It shows the error "Problem on loading widget" on the screen. Logcat shows nothing. Any clues on why that is the case? Or is there any place I can check in my code to see what can be problem? Because the code that extends AppWidgetProvider called the method onEnabled(Context context) and exit gracefully. I cannot see what can cause the error...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:columnCount="1"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/wl_s00_0"
        >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_s00_0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/anim_s00_0"
            style="@style/pb_s00_0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/wl_s01_0"
        >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_s01_0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/anim_s01_0"
            style="@style/pb_s01_0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

The above code shows of widget_layout.xml. The LinearLayout will either visible or gone depends on my code status. Originally it is visible, so can be able to see the ProgressBar there. The ProgressBar element contains a drawable that is an animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list android:oneshot="false" android:visible="true" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/emoji_smiley_51_1" android:duration="5000" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/emoji_smiley_51_2" android:duration="5000" />
</animation-list>
```

I do not have any extra code except specify the widget in the Manifest file.

Here are the code related to updateWidget.

```
public void updateWidget() {
        ComponentName widgetComponentName = new ComponentName(this, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

        int[] widgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widgetComponentName);

        for (int widgetId : widgetIds) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            int currentVisibleId = getDisplayComponentId(); // a method to check which LinearLayout should be hidden, which should display

            for (int displayComponentId : PetWidgetManager.stateLayoutList) {
                if (displayComponentId == currentVisibleId) {
                    remoteViews.setViewVisibility(displayComponentId, View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    remoteViews.setViewVisibility(displayComponentId, View.GONE);
                }
            }
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }
```

One thing I found is that if before installation of app, I reboot the device, then after installation, the widget can load without problem. However, if I just install without reboot, every time, the widget will shows "Problem loading widget". No clues on that...

Comment: Have you got the code for the custom widget?

Comment: if you want some help, you need to post here so code.... it can be problem cuz of service or something else. Post some code..

Comment: Added ... that's all the code related to the widget... after first installation of the app, drag the widget to put it on screen, the widget shows "Problem on loading widget". LogCat has nothing...

Comment: There is code related to filling remoteview?

Comment: Added some codes that run for update widget, really that's all